# How to set Mongo Id to null when creating a new object using Spring MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

Hi I am new to spring and mongo. I am trying to save a new object and setting its mongo id to null. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: By "mongo id", do you mean the document's `"_id"` field?  If so, `null` seems like a poor choice for a value.

Comment: yes, I have to set the "_id" field to null and I am having a hard time testing to see if the id is indeed null

Comment: Assert.assertTrue(savedObject.getId() == null)

Comment: This [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BtydtR1TnCr) doesn't seem to have a problem testing for `null`.  Maybe you could share more of your code?  And, why would you want to set `"_id"` to `null`?